# Colcon commands

Tags: ros, ros2, catkin, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm new to ROS 2 and recently started using it for a project. I have been using ROS (1) for the last year and really liked the catkin_tools. I guess it's easier to use. I'm wondering if there are analogues commands in colon build. Commands like *catkin clean*, *catkin list*. In addition, is it possible to build only certain packages in colcon?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382017/colcon-commands/) by [Anjulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/57623/anjulo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Anjulo,

> Commands like catkin clean

```
rm -r build install
```

I think colon does not have any clean command. For that have a look at the below links.

https://answers.ros.org/question/330109/ros2-workspace-clean/
https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/37

> catkin list

```
colcon-package-information
```

https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/verb/list.html

> In addition, is it possible to build only certain packages in colcon?

```
colcon build --packages-select <name-of-pkg>
```

If you only want to build selected package from workspace:

```
colcon build --packages-select <name-of-pkg> <name-of-another-pkg>
```

https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/how-to.html?highlight=colcon%20build%20--packages-selec#build-only-a-single-package-or-selected-packages

I think this will help you. This is a good official user documentation: https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/index.html.

Moreover, You can also have a look at this documentation by Dirk Thomas:  https://docplayer.net/207294236-Colcon-documentation-dirk-thomas-nov-05-2020.html

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anjulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/57623/anjulo/) on 2021-07-08**:
Thanks man!